# JMS ActiveMQ lock with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jms, activemq-classic

My project uses JMS with ActiveMQ and it works fine, both in production and when I run my tests local computer. My problem occurs when Jenkins runs my tests (the same ones that are successful in my computer), I get the following entry in the console output:

> 2016-11-17 12:17:19,277 INFO  o.a.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker
>   Database activemq-data/localhost/KahaDB/lock is locked... waiting 10
>   seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException:
>   File 'activemq-data/localhost/KahaDB/lock' could not be locked.

Has anyone had the same experience and encountered a solution for the problem? Will be much grateful for your help!

More details of the console output:

> 2016-11-17 12:17:09,193 WARN  o.a.a.broker.jmx.ManagementContext
>   Failed to start jmx connector: Cannot bind to URL
>   [rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException:
>   jmxrmi [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi].
>   Will restart management to re-create jmx connector, trying to remedy
>   this issue.
>
> 2016-11-17 12:17:09,257 INFO  o.a.a.store.kahadb.plist.PListStore
>   PListStore:[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mydir/workspace/myproject/activemq-data/localhost/tmp_storage]
>   started
>
> 2016-11-17 12:17:09,271 INFO  o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService Using
>   Persistence Adapter:
>   KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mydir/workspace/myproject/activemq-data/localhost/KahaDB]
>
> 2016-11-17 12:17:09,277 INFO  o.a.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker
>   Database activemq-data/localhost/KahaDB/lock is locked... waiting 10
>   seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException:
>   File 'activemq-data/localhost/KahaDB/lock' could not be locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem. The build process running in Jenkins hanged during the testing phase and I was forced to abort it, which left a lock in the directory: dir-tests\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB. There are two ways to address this problem:

1) The most direct and correct solution is to delete dir-tests\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB\lock, however I do not have access nor permissions in the remote Jenkins machine.

2) We can easily create the Jms broker with a different name, e.g.

```
 brokerService.setBrokerName("MyDummyBrokerName");
```

This causes Active-MQ to use the directory dir-tests\activemq-data\MyDummyBrokerName\KahaDB, which means that it will use a different lock.
However, this is a workaround and not a final solution because the old lock and corresponding directory will remain in Jenkins. Nevertheless, it solves the problem for the time being and the old locks can be deleted later.

Comment: João: glad to hear your issue was resolved! Would you please accept+up vote my answer, since it was correct?

Comment: Or you can also accept your own answer if you think it's more relevant or better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a previous ActiveMQ process still running that has locked the data store. This new instance you see is running as a "slave" and polling to acquire the lock.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not that simple :(

Comment: Might not be a separate process.. the message that the JMX cannot initialize "javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException" indicates that your test maybe trying to re-register a broker within the same JVM. The lock message indicates some thread (current process or other) has already locked the data store.